# Getting read timeout error on pentaho on calling pentaho reports

Tags: pentaho

I am using pentaho bi server 4.5 version, I have huge data for the particular tenant. When I am trying to generate report for particular period .. It is giving error as "Read Timeout" . And displaying as below :

ERROR

The requested URL could not be retrieved
While trying to retrieve the URL: http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:8081/pentaho/ViewAction?
The following error was encountered:
Read Timeout
The system returned:
    [No Error]
A Timeout occurred while waiting to read data from the network. The network or server may be down or congested. Please retry your request.

Please help me out.

And also need help on how to increase the read time on bi server.

Thanks in advance,
Mounesh

Comment: I tried setting for session time out in web.xml and connectiontimeOut in server.xml. Also made changes in admin console. Still no luck

Comment: I am able to get the excel report on pentaho report designer but from bi server I could not

Answer (score 0):

We can control the query timeout for PRPTs as follows.

> Master Report > Attributes > query > timeout

Here you can define the how many seconds the report times out.

> Master Report > Attributes > query > limit

Here you can define how many rows are returned to the report.

[image]

If using the Manage Data Sources Perspective in PUC you can add an extra property to set the query timeout.

[image]

This `socketTimeout` is valid for PostgreSQL and MySQL if you use any other DB let me know.

For further knowledge:

> /biserver-ee/pentaho-solutions/system/mondrian/mondrian.properties

```
mondrian.rolap.queryTimeout=300
```

This accounts for Analyzer/ Mondrian timeouts.